# Multiple html files in Email body

Tags: html, linux, bash, sendmail, mailx

i have multiple csv files:

I'm using this script to get html output:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pandas as pd
import sys
import json
sys.stdout = open('output.html','wt')

df = pd.read_csv('users.csv')
print(df.to_html())
```

For other file

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pandas as pd
import sys
import json
sys.stdout = open('output1.html','wt')

df = pd.read_csv('groups.csv')
print(df.to_html())
```

created mailheader file

```
To: user@example.com
Subject: my subject
Content-Type: text/html
```

Then run:

```
cat mailheader output.html output1.html | sendmail -t
```

It attaches both files into email body, but i would like to add file name and space between tables, is it possible ?

```
    users.csv 

    output.html content

    groups.csv 

   output1.html
```

desired output:https://1drv.ms/w/s!AizscpxS0QM4hJo7PSSUarnfy8BEvg

Sorry for doc file, space between 2 tables doesn't have to be so large, just couldn't reduce it

Comment: Post your expected output and your efforts towards reachign it

Comment: @Inian-thanks, just did it

Comment: search for info about mime mail/mime types. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

to each file added

```
<br></br>
        <caption><b>Some Title</b></caption>
        <br></br>
```

and perpended each file

```
echo -e "<br></br>\n\t<caption><b>HTML E-mail</b></caption>\n\t<br></br>\n$(cat 1.html)" > output1.html
```

and send it:`cat mailheader output.html output1.html output3 output4 | sendmail -t`